# How to preserve square brackets while creating an URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, url, networking

I have `let urlString = "https://example.com/[path]/file.txt"`.
How to create URL object, but preserve square brackets and not converting it to %5B and %5D.
Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want that? As far as I know, the only valid use of square brackets in an URI is if the host is given as an IP address, e.g. [127.0.0.1], and they *must* be percent-escaped otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't, by design. That isn't a valid URL, so it can't be expressed with `URL`.

Long version:

The path component of a URI (including URLs) is defined by [RFC 3986 Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3). The allowed characters in each segment (between `/`) are called `pchar`, defined as follows:

```
pchar       = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
pct-encoded = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

`[` and `]` are not on that list, and so cannot be in the path. You must percent-encode them.

You are free to create a String that includes those characters, but it cannot be an URL.